Angular Universal (19) SSG and SSR Hybrid, does not serve static files
I'm playing with new ( v19 ) Universal.
Im trying to use Hybrid approach, so some pages like home, about, products would be prerendered in build time ( SSG ) while 'dynamic' pages like checkout or my-account would be client side, or server side rendered.
I've created a new dummy app, with 3 pages: Home, About and Checkout with routing like this:
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    component: AboutComponent,
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    component: CheckoutComponent
  }
];

And then router.server.ts like this:
export const serverRoutes: ServerRoute[] = [
  {
    path: 'home',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Prerender
  },
  {
    path: 'about',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Prerender
  },
  {
    path: 'checkout',
    renderMode: RenderMode.Client
  }
];

I ran ng build, and the app seems to be built correctly - it prerendered Home and Checkout, and now I can see there is 'browser' and 'server' folders in my dist, and those 2 prerendered sites are correctly placed in browser folder.
Now I run serve:ssr:unitest, app is being served, but whole app, seems to be server side rendered. I've manually modified prerendered static html files inside dist, and I cannot see any changes, so my guess is, this server.ts does not serve my static files?
I would expect our server.ts to serve static files first, and if those are not present, it could use SSR/CSR?
Am im being dumb, or is there something im missing? Should I use some different serving approach for hybrid approach? If so, what would be the best way to do that?
Another question - how to handle routerlinks in hybrid SSG/SSR approach? using regular routetLink directive seems to make the app switch to client side routing? Should I just use classic a href?
Thanks in advance for any help

You question lacks a bit of details. Are you saying that if you ask for /home you're getting an SSR'd response ?

@MatthieuRiegler Yes. at least that's what I understand.
My steps to make this conslusion are:
1 -  run serve:ssr:unitest
2 - go to localhost:4000/home   -> I can see homepage
3 - in code editor, go to dist/appname/browser/home/index.html and modify that file with some random content
4 - in browser go again to localhost:4000/home - and I still can see the same homepage as before (without changes from step 3 ), so my conclusion is - it's server side rendered. ( i've tried to do step 4 on different browsers or incognito so it's rather not cache thing )

You don't have hot reload when running a prod build. Did you restart your server after each change ?

Your server that handles the actual request (and stands in front of your express app), should try to find files locally, and if not found - pass request to your express app (see server.ts). You can't test it locally.

@OZ_ ok, you were right. I was kind of hoping, that this server.ts will handle everything out of the box :) I have setup nginx to try to serve static file first, and if not It would pass the request to express server, and it works great. Another thing to mention is, that I had to replace all routerlinks with classic  to prevent client side routing, and make all traffic goes through nginx first. Thank you!
